# what is the syntax for jx:each within jx:each in jxls2

Tags: jxls

I've been using jxls 1.0.5 for a while, and just recently saw a need to migrate to 2.2.5,

in jxls 1.0.5 i'm able to embed a  statement within another  statement.

```
<jx:forEach items="${homeDwellers}" var="homeDweller">
<jx:forEach items="${homeDweller.chores}" var="chore">
</jx:forEach>
</jx:forEach>
```

How is this done with 2.2.5 where i'm only entering a comment for jx:each?

```
A1: jx:each(items="homeDwellers" var="homeDweller" lastCell="B3")
A2: jx:each(items="homeDweller.chores" var="chore" lastCell="B2")
```

??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define as many inner commands as you need in a single multi-line cell comment

```
jx:each(items="homeDwellers" var="homeDweller" lastCell="B3")
jx:each(items="homeDweller.chores" var="chore" lastCell="B2")
```

They will be embedded in that same order.
See similar example in the [documentation](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/excel_markup.html).

Also you may want to check a [comment_markup_demo.xls](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/raw/7925f98008236e13b80bcbfa1859891b19b78982/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/comment_markup_demo.xls) template in jxls-demo project which demonstrates various markup options.